# Getting linker settings in post build script

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, post-build-event

I was trying to write a post build script which should copy all required *dll*s into the `$(OutDir)` directory. Therefore the script has to know the list of `AdditionalLibraryDirectories` and `AdditionalDependencies` to do the copying process.

Does someone know how to access them in the post-build-Event script?

Comment: It might be easier to add a custom msbuild target to the project file, it's syntax usually makes it way easier to copy things around like this, especially compared to batch files. You can then reference libraries like @(Link->'%(AdditionalDependencies )')

Comment: @stijn This sounds interesting. Could you give more Details?

Comment: @stijn Can you iterate through the items of these lists via a custome msbuild Task?

Comment: Yes though I think it might be possible with a custom Target as well. I'll see if I can come up with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be a start, add it somewhere in your project file after the `<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets"/>` line:

```
<Target Name="GetFullLibPaths" AfterTargets="Build">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Libs Include="%(Link.AdditionalDependencies)"/>
    <LibDirs Include="%(Link.AdditionalLibraryDirectories)"/>
    <!-- Combine them, 'cross product' -->
    <LibsAndDirs Include="@(Libs)">
      <Dir>%(LibDirs.Identity)</Dir>
    </LibsAndDirs>
    <!-- Filter on those which actually exist -->
    <LibPaths Include="@(LibsAndDirs)" Condition="Exists('%(LibsAndDirs.Dir)%(LibsAndDirs.Identity)')">
      <FullLibPath>%(Dir)\%(Identity)</FullLibPath>
    </LibPaths>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Message Text="MatchingLibs = %(LibPaths.FullLibPath)" />
</Target>
```

It will run automatically after a build, list libraries and directories, and look for libraries which effectively exist in the library drectories (to skip the standard user32.lib etc).

You can then copy those dlls to OutDir, assuming the dlls are in the library directory as well:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="%(LibPaths.Dir)\%(LibPaths.Filename).dll" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)"/>
```

Comment: After inserting your upper code snippet in the projects vcyproj there is no message in the output window of Visual Studio when compiling this project.

Comment: That's strange, not even `MatchingLibs = `? Where did you insert the code exactly? Does the project build (eg if it's up-to-date already VS won't even start a build)?